# How do I install OpenSSL (Windows)

Tags: windows, openssl

I must be missing something exceptionally simple here, but for the life of me I cannot figure out what I should download/install to allow me to use OpenSSL on Windows.

I need to combine a SSL certificate file (`.cer`) and a private key file into a single `.pfx` for installation into IIS 8.

Everything I've read has said I need to use [OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org) - but I'm struggling to work out **how**!

The website only provides source code (which I'm not willing to spent the time/effort working out how to compile, etc) and a list of [unofficial creators of binary files](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Binaries) but I'm not sure I like using an "unoffical" installer.

It can't be difficult, otherwise people would say "This is how you install OpenSSL, and then this is how you use it"... but instead everybody just says "Use OpenSSL".

Can anybody give me some pointers?

(Disclaimer... I'm a programmer who has the unfortunate task of also managing some servers, as we are too small to employ a specialist network guru)

Comment: There are no official windows builds of openssl. Either you compile it or you use one of the unofficial builds.

Answer (score 1):

Chocolatey is a package manager for Windows.
It can install OpenSSL:
https://chocolatey.org/packages/OpenSSL.Light
You can also try:
https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Binaries
You can also convert between certificates formats if needed.
There's an example for converting PEM to PFX:
https://www.sslsupportdesk.com/openssl-commands

Comment: Hopefully this should help. good luck

Comment: I wasn't keen on installing a package manager for one single package, so I've gone with one of the supplier of the binaries (which, incidentally, I did link that same list in my question)

Answer (score 0):

In windows this is done with

```
C:\> certutil –MergePFX certfile.cer certfile.pfx
```

certutil is always included.